# Directsound no longer works

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, directx

So I was on Windows 7 and was messing with permissions on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in the registry. Something happened and it broke sound. I could not get directsound to work again in media applications that use it such as VLC and Mediamonkey.

When I ran dxdiag.exe, it said everything was working but I didn't have any sound in VLC and VLC's log repeatedly said "directsound error: cannot start playing buffer: (hr=0x80070057)".

So I decided to upgrade to Windows 10 hoping that would fix the problem and after reinstalling the Realtek drivers, I still can not get directsound to function. Dxdiag still says everything is OK but now VLC is saying...

"directsound error: cannot initialize DirectSound
main error: module not functional
main error: failed to create audio output"

When I was on Win7, I tried changing the permissions back. On Win10, I tried removing the Realtek audio device and rescanning for changes and I also tried reinstalling the drivers.

I really don't think the problem is hardware related or has anything to do with my Realtek drivers. I am sure that the problem has to do with the registry and permissions for directx or directsound and had to have been something that would carry over or be unaffected by migrating to a new Windows OS.

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: You tried changing the permissions in what exactly?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Due to the complexity and size of the registry, it is unlikely we'll be able to assist unless you know which specific keys you modified and changed the permissions of. As a rule of thumb you should not do what you were doing unless you're trying to have trouble.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried changing the permission back to what I believe it was before. I tried "Read only" privileges for USERS and ADMINISTRATORS and tried again with "Full control". Neither worked.

Comment: @music2myear The entire HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT hive. I know, I have been an advanced computer used for long enough to know not to mess with the registry.

Comment: @username786571 - You should use a working installation of Windows 7 to determine the correct permissions of that registry key.

Comment: But permissions are not consistent across the entire hive. When you set the permissions at the root of the Hive, those would have propagated across the entire hive, overwriting any other differing permissions across the entire hive. Simply setting the permissions at the root back to what you believe they were is insufficient because of that variance deeper down in the hive, and unless you have an exactly identical computer with the same software and software history, you will not be able to find a precise replication of the previous correct permissions.

Comment: What you should do is perform a repair-installation of Windows, as this should be able to repair the damage done.

Comment: @Ramhound But there is thousands of keys, how am I supposed to know which one(s) are causing this issue?

Comment: @music2myear Wouldn't upgrading to Win10 from Win7 have repaired the installation already?

Comment: @username786571 - An in-place upgrade is not a viable solution to every problem and upgrading to Windows 10 introduces only additional potential problems like driver compatibility.  As for those of keys, you didn’t change the permissions on thousands of keys, you only changed the permissions on the ones you changed.